# can we use single visual studio licence to create multiple projects and sell them?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to know if i buy Visual studio 2017 professional then can i sell multiple projects to multiple clients made in same visual studio licence ? 
or there is any limit like one client to one licence ?

logically there should not be any limit , still wanted to confirm !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are selling "standalone" programs that are pre-built and do not require Visual Studio libraries to be distributed with your program in order for your program to run, there is no limitation.

Where things get a bit tricky is if you *do* have to distribute DLLs supplied by Visual Studio that your program requires. Some of these may have different licensing/conditions/limitations for licensed redistribution. For VS 2017, the list of VS files you are licensed to redistribute with your program can be found here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs . Any libraries on that list with modified licensing conditions that diverge from "you may freely redistribute" (such as ASP.NET libraries) are also annotated there.

Finally, there may be 3rd-party licensed add-on libraries that integrate with Visual Studio that have their own licensing conditions, such as the legacy InstallShield Limited Edition or Visual Studio Installer "wizard" libraries that were provided/sold to automate the installation of your VS-built program.

The full Visual Studio 2017 Professional License Terms can be found here: https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mlt687465/